# How to separate numbers (including dot decimal separator) from letters in `tidyr::separate` regex?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, split, tidyr

How to separate numbers (including dot decimal separator) from letters in `tidyr::separate` regex? In my current attempts, it seems the first letter of the second string is getting chopped off.

Reprex:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c("24.1234AAA", "14.4321BBB"))
df
#>            x
#> 1 24.1234AAA
#> 2 14.4321BBB

# This works but it is missing the first letter of the string
tidyr::separate(df, x, c("part1", "part2"), sep = "[^0-9 | {.}]", extra = "merge", convert = TRUE)
#>     part1 part2
#> 1 24.1234    AA
#> 2 14.4321    BB

# This gets the letter string completely, but not the numbers
tidyr::separate(df, x, c("part1", "part2"), sep = "([0-9.]+)", extra = "merge", convert = TRUE)
#>   part1 part2
#> 1    NA   AAA
#> 2    NA   BBB
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note: the numbers and letters are not always the same length so we cannot use a numeric vector for the `sep` argument of `tidyr::separate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex lookaround to split between the digit (`\\d`) and letter (`[A-Z]`)

```
tidyr::separate(df, x, c("part1", "part2"), 
    sep = "(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Z])", extra = "merge", convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
    part1 part2
1 24.1234   AAA
2 14.4321   BBB
```

---

Or use `extract` with capture groups

```
tidyr::extract(df, x, c("part1", "part2"), "^([0-9.]+)(\\D+)", convert = TRUE)
    part1 part2
1 24.1234   AAA
2 14.4321   BBB
```

Comment: That's fantastic! The first solution works perfectly, but the second one using `extract` is easier to read and understand without the lookaround/lookahead and works just as well. Thanks!

Comment: @akrun. I know that it is not possible. But why can we not do: `library(readr) df %>% 
  mutate(part1= parse_number(x),
         part2 = parse_character(x))`.  part1 works part2 not.